# Tweepy. Make stream run forever

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am relatively new to tweepy python library.
I want to be sure that my stream python script always runs on a remote server. So it would be great if someone will share the best practices on how to make it happen.

Right now I am doing it this way:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

while True:

    try:

        # create instance of the tweepy tweet stream listener
        listener = TweetStreamListener()

        # set twitter keys/tokens
        auth = OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
        auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)

        # create instance of the tweepy stream
        stream = Stream(auth, listener)

        stream.userstream()
    except Exception as e:
        print "Error. Restarting Stream.... Error: "
        print e.__doc__
        print e.message
        time.sleep(5)
```

And I return `False` on each of the methods: `on_error(), on_disconnect(), on_timeout()`.
So, by returning `False` the stream stops and then reconnects in the infinite loop.

Answer (score 6):

Here's how I do mine and it's been running for almost a year, on two computers to handle the errors that stop the stream here and there.

```
#They don't need to be in the loop.
auth = OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)

while True:
    listener = TweetStreamListener()
    stream = Stream(auth, listener, timeout=60)

    try:
        stream.userstream()

    except Exception, e:
        print "Error. Restarting Stream.... Error: "
        print e.__doc__
        print e.message
```

To make sure that it runs forever, you should redefine the `on_error` method to handle the time between reconnection attempts. Your 5 seconds sleeping will hinder your chances to a successful reconnect because Twitter will see that you tried to do it too frequently. But that's another question.

Answer (score 1):

Just my two cents.

I received lots of Error 420, which was weird because I didn't ask for too much keywords to the stream API.

So I figured out that the `on_data()` method of the stream listener class must always return `True`.

Mine returned `False` sometimes, so tweepy cut the connection, and recreate it directly as it was in a loop, twitter didn't like it much...

Answer (score 1):

I've also resolved the problem by creating new stream recursively on exceptions.

Here is my complete code. just change `mytrack` variable, put your keys and run it using `pm2` or `python`.

```
from tweepy import OAuthHandler, Stream, StreamListener
import json


mytrack = ['netmine', 'bitkhar', 'bitcoin']

consumer_key = ""
consumer_secret = ""
access_token = ""
access_token_secret = ""

auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)


class StdOutListener(StreamListener):
    def __init__(self, listener, track_list, repeat_times):
        self.repeat_times = repeat_times
        self.track_list = track_list
        print('************** initialized : #', self.repeat_times)

    def on_data(self, data):
        print(self.repeat_times, 'tweet id : ', json.loads(data)['id'])

    def on_exception(self, exception):
        print('exception', exception)
        new_stream(auth, self.track_list, self.repeat_times+1)

    def on_error(self, status):
        print('err', status)
        if status == 420:
            # returning False in on_data disconnects the stream
            return False


def new_stream(auth, track_list, repeat_times):
    listener = StdOutListener(StreamListener, track_list, repeat_times)
    stream = Stream(auth, listener).filter(track=track_list, is_async=True)


new_stream(auth, mytrack, repeat_times=0)
```

Comment: did it work for you for a long time?

Comment: Yes, It was working on our linux server using PM2 for more than a month without any problem.  I stop the project myself.