# Tweepy StreamListener going stale after a while-- how to properly maintain a stream connection?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, supervisord

I'm building a bot that I'd like to have running persistently (always on/listening) and having an issue with the Tweepy twitter API StreamListener going stale after a while, and becoming unresponsive.

When I start it up, it works great and responds like it should-- but if I leave it sit without getting any input from the stream it kind of zombifies.  Doesn't exit/die, but doesn't get any new data either.

I thought I had logic to account for timeouts, but apparently either I'm not doing it right or that's not the issue.  I should add that I'm using supervisord to run this as a daemon in Ubuntu.

I've identified two possible solutions but wanted to see if there was a 'right' way to do it.  Here's my current setup (excluding the on_data which works great):

```
from tweepy import StreamListener
from tweepy import Stream

class StreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):

    def on_data(self, tweet_payload):
        # do some stuff

    def on_error(self, status_code):
        print >> stderr, "Encountered an error with status code:" 
        sys.stderr.flush()

        # if the error for bad credentials, end stream
        if status_code == 401:
            return False

        # rate limit, close
        if status_code == 420:
            return False

    # When timed out
    def on_timeout(self):

        # Print timeout message
        print >> stderr, "Timeout..."

        # Wait 10 seconds
        time.sleep(60)

        # Return nothing
        return

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

logging.debug("Starting request stream with %s at %s" % (api.me().name, str(datetime.datetime.now())))
stream_listener = StreamListener()
stream = Stream(auth=api.auth, listener=stream_listener)
stream.filter(track=["#hashtagtotrackone", "#hashtagtotracktwo"])
```

One of the solutions I found was to loop the listener block at the end and check for stream.running and if it isn't, delete the stream and start new one.  I believe using `stream.running` and then `stream.disconnect()`  The variant on this is to cycle the feed every so many minutes/hours and reconnect to stay on top of a stale connection.

But another stackoverflow post suggests doing try/except, from:
[Tweepy. Make stream run forever](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29582080/tweepy-make-stream-run-forever)

```
while True:
    listener = TweetStreamListener()
    stream = Stream(auth, listener, timeout=60)

    try:
        stream.filter(track=["#hashtagtotrackone", "#hashtagtotracktwo"])

    except Exception, e:
        print "Error. Restarting Stream.... Error: "
        print e.__doc__
        print e.message
```

Is there a best practice for stream maintenance, ie: letting it handle itself gracefully, or staying on top of it by closing the stream every 24 hours and opening it back up?

The streaming API for tweepy has some good documentation but there aren't any really good examples.  I'm also thinking I should probably use async since this bot will be responding to tweets with the specified hashtag, and I probably want the listener in it's own thread.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you can ask this question in https://codereview.stackexchange.com/